# SQL rtrim is removing first header value

Tags: sql, csv, select

I'm trying to get a properly formatted .csv with the results of a query. I'm new to SQL and so far this is proving frustrating. The original query outputs the header correctly, but doesn't remove the extra spaces in the LOOKUP column which causes problems down the line.

This query:

```
select TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.LOOKUP, TB_SKU_BUCKETS.QOH
from TB_SKU_BUCKETS
inner join TB_SKU_LOOKUPS
on TB_SKU_BUCKETS.SKU_ID=TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.SKU_ID
where TB_SKU_BUCKETS.STORE_ID = '1' 
and TB_SKU_BUCKETS.QOH > '0' 
and TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.LOOKUP not like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-    9]';
```

outputs this:

```
LOOKUP,QOH
730366010008             ,2
185843000285             ,3
185843000278             ,2
810191011729             ,6
```

When I add rtrim(), the data is correct, but LOOKUP is removed.

```
select rtrim(TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.LOOKUP), TB_SKU_BUCKETS.QOH
from TB_SKU_BUCKETS
inner join TB_SKU_LOOKUPS
on TB_SKU_BUCKETS.SKU_ID=TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.SKU_ID
where TB_SKU_BUCKETS.STORE_ID = '1' 
and TB_SKU_BUCKETS.QOH > '0' 
and TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.LOOKUP not like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

produces:

```
,QOH
730366010008,2
185843000285,3
185843000278,2
```

To be clear, I'm looking for results that look like this:

```
LOOKUP,QOH
730366010008,2
185843000285,3
185843000278,2
```

Hopefully this is an easy one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a function to your column name will give different results based on your DBMS, but in this case it simply returns null as columnName. Try using `rtrim(TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.LOOKUP) AS LOOKUP` instead.

Also, for what it's worth, you should try to include your DBMS (sql server, oracle, mysql, etc.) as a tag to your question.

Comment: Stackoverflow to the rescue! Thanks Julien

Answer (score 0):

i believe you need to give the field that you rtrim an alias.

e.g.

```
select rtrim(TB_SKU_LOOKUPS.LOOKUP) as Lookup
```